# Best Approach For Static Background Image?

Tags: unity, camera

I want to have a static background image of a sky that stays completely flat on screen and perfectly fits my games 1920 x 1080 display. Similar to what most old 2D side scrollers did. In other words, I **don't** want to simply drag an image of the sky backward on the Z-axis in 3D space.

Originally, what I was doing to accomplish this was having a 2D "base" camera solely dedicated to rendering this sky image behind everything. I then used a a separate 3D "Overlay" camera to render everything else on top of it.

Here's an example, the blocked out sky section would be the base 2D camera and everything else on screen would be the 3D overlay camera:
[image]

This accomplished exactly what I needed, but I think having my base camera only render the sky, and having an overlay camera render everything else is a bad idea.

Does anyone have a better way of accomplishing this? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Myself, I'd just make this image/sprite renderer a child of the camera, so that no matter how the camera moves, the sky stays attached to it and gets rendered in exactly the same way. By moving it sufficiently far away along the camera's z axis, it won't clip anything rendered closer.

Comment: This is a really great idea for getting the background image to not move. But my background image is unfortunately 1920 x 1080. So, when I pull it farther back in the Z axis, so that it doesn't clip anything rendered closer, it no longer fits the screen size. I believe the way I was doing this originally might be the only real solution, but this is probably my best alternative. Thank you, Douglas! :)

Comment: You know you can scale it up to fill the screen at *any* depth, right? The pixel dimension has no fixed relationship to the world size - you are in full control of that mapping as a game developer. You can use the Pixels per Unit or Transform Scale properties to adjust it as needed.

Comment: If you want to get real fancy, [you can make a custom shader that maps a quad to the full viewport automatically](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/204169/39518), so you don't have to fiddle with scaling numbers, but I think that might be overkill for a case like this.

Comment: Your idea is honestly much better than mine. I'm trying to incorporate it now. I didn't want to make this answered thread messier, so I made a new post about it here:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/204167/resize-sprite-to-match-screen-size